# Algorithm to create balanced teams based on multiple criteria

Tags: algorithms

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but here goes:

I have a set of players in 3 age groups.  Each player has the attributes:

- gender
- mental skill (1-10)
- physical skill (1-10)
- age group (1-3)

I want to sort them into 14 teams that have balanced "stats", as in each team has (or as close as possible):

- same number of players on each team
- same number of each gender as each other team
- same average mental skill
- same average physical skill
- for each age group, same number of players from each age group on each team

What sort of algorithm or method would I use to do this?  An example in python would be great.

As a follow up:

I want to hand-pick two members for each team and have them fixed, how would I build the rest of the teams around that in order to meet the balanced team criteria? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the approaches you have tried so far?

Comment: Usually you probably won't be able to find an arrangement that has exact equality in all five categories.  Moreover, the way to minimize the difference in average mental skill might not be the way to minimize the difference in average physical skill.  So, you'll have to figure out how you want to trade off between these 5 considerations.  Before the problem is solvable (or even well-specified), you need to identify  a *single* objective function that you want to minimize.  That objective function is a quantitative representation of the tradeoffs between these 5 differences.

Comment: Coding questions and requests for code are off-topic here, but questions about algorithms are suitable.  I encourage you to edit your question based upon all the comments you've received so far.